# wxpython GridBagSizer inside a wx.ScrolledWindow not resizing correctly when you snap the Frame to a side of the screen in Microsoft Windows

Tags: python, wxpython

EDIT: This seems to only happen in MS Windows 7 Pro and MS Windows 7 Home. It doesn't happen in Ubuntu 10.04.

Here's some example code of the problem I'm having:

```
import wx as wx

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        #Panel that holds all the other panels
        self.mainPanel = wx.ScrolledWindow(self, -1)
        self.mainPanel.SetScrollbars(1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.mainPanel.SetBackgroundColour("LIGHT GREY")

        #Panels in mainPanel
        self.lefttopPanel = wx.Panel(self.mainPanel, -1)
        self.lefttopPanel.SetBackgroundColour("WHITE")        
        self.sizewidgets(self.panelwidgets(
                         text='Left Top Panel', 
                         num=12,
                         parent=self.lefttopPanel),
                         parent=self.lefttopPanel)        

        self.leftmiddlePanel = wx.Panel(self.mainPanel, -1)
        self.leftmiddlePanel.SetBackgroundColour("WHITE")        
        self.sizewidgets(self.panelwidgets(
                         text='Left Middle Panel',
                         num=6,
                         parent=self.leftmiddlePanel),
                         parent=self.leftmiddlePanel)

        self.leftbottomPanel = wx.Panel(self.mainPanel, -1)
        self.leftbottomPanel.SetBackgroundColour("WHITE")
        self.sizewidgets(self.panelwidgets(
                         text='Left Bottom Panel',
                         num=8,
                         parent=self.leftbottomPanel),
                         parent=self.leftbottomPanel)

        self.righttopPanel = wx.Panel(self.mainPanel, -1)
        self.righttopPanel.SetBackgroundColour("WHITE")        
        self.sizewidgets(self.panelwidgets(
                         text='Right Top Panel',
                         num=8,
                         parent=self.righttopPanel),
                         parent=self.righttopPanel)

        self.rightbottomPanel = wx.Panel(self.mainPanel, -1)
        self.rightbottomPanel.SetBackgroundColour("WHITE")
        self.sizewidgets(self.panelwidgets(
                         text='Right Bottom Panel',
                         num=8,
                         parent=self.rightbottomPanel),
                         parent=self.rightbottomPanel)


        mpsizer = wx.GridBagSizer(vgap=4, hgap=4)
        mpsizer.Add(self.lefttopPanel, pos=(0,0), span=(1,1), flag=wx.EXPAND)
        mpsizer.Add(self.leftmiddlePanel, pos=(1,0), span=(1,1), flag=wx.EXPAND)
        mpsizer.Add(self.leftbottomPanel, pos=(2,0), span=(1,2), flag=wx.EXPAND)
        mpsizer.Add(self.righttopPanel, pos=(0,1), span=(2,2), flag=wx.EXPAND)
        mpsizer.Add(self.rightbottomPanel, pos=(2,2), span=(1,1), flag=wx.EXPAND)
        mpsizer.AddGrowableCol(1)
        mpsizer.AddGrowableRow(1)
        self.mainPanel.SetSizer(mpsizer)

        #Adding a refresh to resize event
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.OnResize)

        self.Show()

    def OnResize(self, event):
        self.Refresh()
        event.Skip()

    def sizewidgets(self, widgetlist , parent):
        psizer = wx.GridSizer(cols=2, vgap=5,hgap=5)
        for widget in widgetlist:
            psizer.Add(widget)
        parent.SetSizer(psizer)



    def panelwidgets(self, text, num, parent):
        widgets = []
        for i in range(num):
            widgets += [wx.StaticText(parent, label=text)]
        return widgets

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    MainFrame(None, size=(800, 800), title="GridBagSizer Problem")
    app.MainLoop()
```

Without the refresh on EVT_SIZE it causes some of the widgets to be drawn incorrectly. Here's an example of what it looks like (https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYEF4.png).

If you add a refresh to EVT_SIZE it fixes most of the sizing issues except when you snap the Frame to half of the screen in MS Windows. Here's an example of what that looks like (https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKTPi.png).

What I can't figure out is why it keeps drawing the bottomrightPanel incorrectly. It looks like it draws it from the bottom of that panel instead of from the top. If you resize the frame at all it redraws it correctly and give you the behavior you'd expect.

It seems like the growablecolumn is causing the issue but I can't seem to fix it and keep the behavior I want. I've tried calling self.bottomrightPanel.Layout() on resize but that seems to do nothing. I also tried calling self.bottomrightPanel.Fit() on resize which fixes the issue when you snap the Frame to half of the screen but it screws up the look of the mainPanel (which causes it to look really bad). If anyone out there knows how to fix the problem (without changing the type of sizer which I've already done in my current app) I'd be very appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem right now. I've narrowed it down to the wx.ScrolledWindow. If you can change this to a wx.Panel it may clear up the problem. I'm still looking into fixing the scrolled window issue.